# Is the Like Button the only currently supported method for posting a webpage to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The *Like Button* seems like a very specific, and not very elegant in my opinion, solution to allowing users to post a web page to their Facebook profile. You have two options: 1) Use the iFrame solution, which allows very little flexibility in functionality, integration or appearance or 2) the XFBML solution which requires loading the entire Facebook javascript SDK just for one little "share this" button.

Is the *Like Button* the only way that is currently supported by Facebook to allow sharing of content to a user's Facebook profile? It seems to be the only method mentioned anywhere in the Facebook developer documentation, and I've had trouble finding any alternatives elsewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a service called Facebook Share:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<your url>&t=<your title>
```

I *guess* it's still working **but** I'm seeing people having troubles using it and Facebook is forcing developers to use the Like Plugin.

Now:

1. Most likely your visitors will have the Facebook JS Library cached on their browsers
2. Facebook uses CDNs and their servers are super fast
3. Even if it doesn't fit in your design, don't forget that users are *used* to it
4. You can create a Facebook Application and use the Graph API but it's way more complicated
5. Don't use their services!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll shy away from the old Share functionality to prevent future headache. I assume the 'Don't use their Services' line was intended to mean 'If you don't like their way, don't use it!'. That's fine, but some people want full control over the visual experience of a website, and the iFrame Like Button solution really doesn't allow for that. Not all users are dumb, and a well-crafted experience doesn't always require a button that screams "I'm a Facebook Like Button! Click Me!"

Comment: @cmal: yes that's what I meant by the last point. It's not being dump or not...you see the users are used to see it anyway, and you can track the clicks on it...if you see it's not  adding any benefits (social love) to your website, then remove it to maintain the user experience!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Facebook share is the simplest and most natural solution to share content on your FB profile.

You may want to read [this article](http://www.yourseoplan.com/ask-the-experts-facebook-like-vs-share-whats-the-difference/).